# Export table from mysql with unicode into csv file via java

Tags: java, mysql, csv, unicode

i need to export a table from mysql with unicode into a csv file via java. it is exporting fine in excel but the unicode tamil fonts are not displaying.

code for database connection:

```
        String db_dburl = "jdbc:mysql://"+Config.databaseip+":3306/"+Config.databasename;
        String dburl_unicode = db_dburl.concat("?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8"); 
        Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl_unicode, Config.databaseuname, Config.databasepwd);
```

original data:
4   AC கலை-கலாசாரம் - ARTS CULTURE  AW விருதுகள்  விழாக்கள் -  AWARDS  FUNCTIONS
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to open csv file in notepad not in excel sheet?

Comment: yes it is opening as is in notepad

Comment: But when i export with utf-16 format it is exporting fine directly but it is not possible using "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-16"

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the file encoding in java options during runtime. For example, if Tomcat web server is your runtime: Add to arguments the following
   -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"

or set the environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS as -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

First include following .jar file

you need to add the `opencsv-2.3.jar`

Refer This code.

```
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;    
    import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

    public class WriteCSV {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {
                String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select id_movie, movie_name from movies");
                String csv = "E:\\dummyFolder\\output2.csv";
                CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));
                List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    data.add(new String[] { rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2) });
                }
                writer.writeAll(data);
                System.out.println("CSV written successfully.");
                writer.close();

            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```